# html2canvas unable to download

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code below that contains a simple `hello world` html page i'm trying to use the library `html2canvas` to try to download the canvas but it doesn't seem to be working i'm following a tutorial i saw but it doesn't work am i doing something wrong below? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```js
function sendData() {
    html2canvas(document.getElementById('capture')).then(function (canvas) {
            $('#capture').append(canvas);
            $('#match-button').attr('href', canvas.toDataURL('image/png'));
            $('#match-button').attr('download', 'Test.png');
            $('#match-button')[0].click();
        });
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="//#" />
     <script type="text/javascript" src="https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="capture" style="padding: 10px; background: #f5da55">
        <h4 style="color: #000; ">Helloo world!</h4>
    </div>
    <div id="match-button" onclick="sendData();">capture</div>



    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all. If **test** is an id of some element, jQuery syntax requires **#** before it.

```
$('#test')
```

Then, html2canvas **onrendered** option is deprecated. Use then() method instead as described on the official site https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/. I could not find **test** element in html snippet from the question, so I added it after the match-button. The modified code looks like this:

```
<script>
function sendData() {
    html2canvas(document.getElementById('capture')).then(function (canvas) {
            $('#capture').append(canvas);
            $('#test').attr('href', canvas.toDataURL('image/png'));
            $('#test').attr('download', 'Test.png');
            $('#test')[0].click();
        });
    }
</script>
...
<div id="capture" style="padding: 10px; background: #f5da55">
    <h4 style="color: #000; ">Helloo world!</h4>
</div>
<div id="match-button" onclick="sendData();">capture</div>
<a id="test" href="#"></a>
```

Comment: I have updated the fiddle above it just seems to be not working the console just goes crazy.

Comment: You call click() method of match-button from the onclick event of the same button, it's infinite recursion. Try to add another element for downloading the file. E.g. as link with id=test from my answer. Smth. like this - https://jsfiddle.net/m6za5qxk/16/

Comment: Ahh it works so it was because i was using the same button to append and download thats why it doesn't work?

Comment: Yes, it caused infinite 'click' recursion.